# TDS[Tabular Data stream protocol] int type

Tags: sql, protocols, tabular

Following the TDS spec, I can`t understand if `int` types are signed or not.
For example is `tinyint`, having hex value `0xFF`, represents -`1` or `255`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN for T-SQL has [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187745.aspx):

```
Data type   Range                                                                      Storage
bigint      -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)   8 Bytes
int         -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)                           4 Bytes
smallint    -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)                                         2 Bytes
tinyint     0 to 255                                                                   1 Byte
```

Which implies that tinyint is unsigned, but all other (smallint, int, bigint) are signed.

At least this is how SQL Server interprets types in T-SQL, so you should interpret data in TDS in the same way.